# Process Builder Immediate Actions & Scheduled Actions on same Criteria?

Tags: process-builder

@DavidReed
@sfdcfox

I'm trying to see if this is set up correctly. I have Immediate Actions & Scheduled Actions running off of the same Criteria.

The problem is, my Immediate Actions are not firing. If I remove the Scheduled Actions, activate, run the test, then my immediate actions *will fire*.

**Edit**

If I put "Set Deactivated Date" & "Change Profile to ID *xyz*" under Immediate Actions, then it works fine. But the moment I split them up and add "Change Profile to ID *xyz*" to the Schedule Action, nothing happens...[image]

:

enter image description here

[image]

+

[image]

+

[image]

+

[image]

+

---

---

---

---

Comment: can you add criteria for immediate and scheduled action?